# How to Parse XML like Dictonary in Python

Tags: json, dictionary

I am new to Python and I been trying to get below fnames Parsed and having hard time doing so.

I need to parse below fNames...

```
{"values":
    {"entries":"uri", "type":"xs:string", "unique-value":
        [{"entry":1, "fName":"\/abc.txt"},
         {"entry":1, "fName":"\/def.txt"},
         {"entry":1, "fName":"\/xyz.txt"},
         {"entry":1, "fName":"\/file.doc"},
         {"entry":1, "fName":"\/file2.txt"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my Code:

```
for entry in j['values']['entries']:
    print entry['entry']['fName']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not enterily sure what you mean with parse, but if you simply want to get the values of fName, you could simply loop through list like this:

```
import json
text = """{.....}"""
json_data = json.loads(text)
for value in json_data['values']['unique-value']:
    print "entry:", value['entry'], "-- fName:", value['fName']
```

**Output:**

```
entry: 1 -- fName: /abc.txt
entry: 1 -- fName: /def.txt
entry: 1 -- fName: /xyz.txt
entry: 1 -- fName: /file.doc
entry: 1 -- fName: /file2.txt
```

The reason that your code didn't work was because both `entry` and `fName` are both key/values from the same dictionary. This means that for your code to work, the json layout would have to look like this:

```
[{"entry": {"fName": "/abc.txt"}}, {"entry": {"fName": "/def.txt"}}]
```

Comment: Omg, that worked and your response was so fast.  Thanks so much.  I will try to understand this in detail.